# Advice for components for a Multi Device program in Delphi Berlin

Tags: database, report, delphi-2010, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a Delphi 5 app that has too many 3rd party components to move to Delphi 10.1, so I am starting from scratch and need some advice from some Experts out there.

It basically is a database program that used DBISAM with a CSV importing and an I used Report Builder for building reports from the data. My goal is to create a multi-device application (Win64 and MacOS). I thought Fast Reports would work but I don't see it as an option for a multi-device program (even after downloading the Fast Reports FMX Install from Embarcadro for Berlin). I was going to use IBLite for a small database, but again don't see this installed. I was told by Embarcadero these components would work for the multi-device app I had in mind.

Any suggestions on where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure but you may not find a DBISAM driver for mobile platforms. You should also keep in mind that it is not good idea to load mobile device with CPU consuming tasks. I would suggest to use multi-tire approach. You should divide your application into several parts. In other words you should have a back-end server and a light-weight client implementing UI to your server.

I also think that you do not need to start from scratch. You may improve the existing application step-by-step. First of all you need to understand how to isolate your busyness logic from UI. You may do it even on Delphi 5.

Sorry my answer is too general, but your question does not have enough details too

Comment: For this program, I am only targeting Windows 32/64 and MacOS. DBISAM was am easy to use database engine since I came from BDE and just didn't have to deal with the BDE crap since the engine was embedded. Fast Report for will work for both OS's, now I am just trying to figure out a simple embed database engine to use that is as close to the DBISAM functions as possible. The program is going to have small tables, possible master/detail, but nothing complicated. One user on one pc or mac. Just a simple CSV import to a table and a way to create visible reports. No sharing what so ever.